# Where can I find user created camera and lens profiles for Lightroom 3 and Camera Raw 6.1?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing

The new Lightroom 3 and Adobe Camera Raw 6.1 have a lens and body database included to automatically correct your image.

For a small description of [this new features](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/features/?view=topnew):

> Quickly and easily perfect your images
>   by automatically reducing lens defects
>   like geometric distortion, chromatic
>   aberration, and vignetting with
>   single-click profiles. Even images
>   from the best lenses will be improved.

But the problem is, for Nikon and Canon, only a limited set of lenses and bodies are included, Adobe has released a program to create your [own lens profiles](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/lensprofile_creator/) but I haven't been able to find a community which posts their profiles. I image a nice database for this could be created to share these profiles with others.

So is there a community which shares these profiles or does everyone keep the profiles private?

To clarify, yes I know that in Photoshop you can search for other submitted profiles, but it seems to lack quality control and cannot be used in Lightroom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking this question and searching some more I found a Adobe employee confirming they were creating a site for this purpose. See: [[suggestion] shared profiles server](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/682560?tstart=0).

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [Adobe Lens Profile Downloader](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/lensprofile_creator.html) (*not* the Creator). The Downloader will let you download and install user-created lens profiles, and they will work with Lightroom, Camera Raw, and Photoshop.

In addition to downloading the profiles, the tool shows ratings and comments on the profiles:

> Adobe Lens Profile Downloader is a free companion application to Photoshop CS5, Photoshop Lightroom 3, and the Camera Raw 6 plug-in. It allows customers to search, download, rate and comment on the online lens correction profiles that are created and shared by the user community.

[image]

Comment: Does this tool address the question of quality control (or ratings, at least)?

Comment: @mattdm Thanks, I've edited my answer to address that aspect. The description from Adobe says that it provides ratings and comments. I've used the tool, but I don't remember that aspect specifically, and cannot run it myself at the moment.

Comment: Tried it and uploaded a screenshot showing comments and rating. The functionality is there, but it is not very heavily used.

Comment: This tool is no longer available... :(